# How to programmatically make a field in a GridView editable along with AutoGenerateEditButton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I'm updating with some SQL data programmatically, and I'd like to use the built in ASP.NET function AutoGenerateEditButton to edit a specific cell. When I populate my GridView with data, it looks like this with AutoGenerateEditButton = True. I'm a bit limited in what info I can show I'm afraid, but this should get the picture across. [My current GridView.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF6xi.png)

I've got a function tied to those auto generated edit buttons that is firing correctly when clicked, represented by this function:

```
Protected Sub grd_ingredientview_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Firing Edit');</script>")

End Sub
```

Now, a couple things.

1. I don't know how to tell what row I've pressed the Edit button on, which I'm assuming matters to editing a specific cell.
2. I need to turn the row's last cell into an editable text box, type in a new value, and then submit it back to my SQL table when confirmed. I can handle the SQL side of all that, but I'm not sure how to turn that cell editable.

I know that if you use all the Edit Button stuff that's built into GridView from the Design view side of things, it makes this super simple. But, I can't use the easy design view side of things to fix this, being I'm already managing so much of it dynamically.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for edit mode in your RowDataBound event

```
            //edit mode
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                // edit mode code 
            }
```